# How to use a random function inside an if statement and use speak function in python at the same time

Tags: python

I'm working on a Virtual Assitant using Python and a few libraries like speech_recognition, gtts, and mpg321.
Now my assistant has one specific reply for any identified dialog, but I want it to reply in a randomized fashion.

Here's the code

```
def violet(data):

    if "what is violet" in data:
        speak("Yours truly.")

    if "are you a robot" in data:
        speak("I don't know what you've heard but virtual assistants have feelings too!")
```

How to use the random function here?

Comment: Are you aware of `random.choice(seq)`?

Answer (score 1):

This should do the trick by using the `random` feature of choosing randomly from a sequence.

```
import random
# ...
speak(random.choice(["Yours truly.", "It is what you are talking to."]))
```